# How to make program (c#, selenium) wait to periodically check if the 'if' condition is met

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I intend to increment the counter by 1 when the url changes and return the final count, eg 10 if url changes 10 times. The program has to wait until the user clicks a button or something on the webpage which leads to the change of url. The code isn't giving the desired output, infact the counter isn't incrementing at all.

```
    public partial class Counter : Form 
    {    
        int count = 0;
        string url = "...";
        private IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        public Counter()
        {
        
           InitializeComponen();
           driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }
        
        private void textBox.TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = "Click: " + count.ToString();
            driver.Manage().Timeout().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            if (driver.Url != url)
            {
                 count++;
                 textBox.Text = "Click: " + count.ToString();
        
            }
        }
        
            private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                count = 0;
                textBox.Text = "Click: " + count.ToString();
        
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: let me get this correctly, you want to count how many time the url has changed while the user is browsing right ?

Comment: Yes, you're right!